# Subdivide faces of Object to a minimum distance of vertices

Tags: vertices

I have the following shape: [image: Virus Shape]

I need all vertices of the shape to have roughly the same distance to each other (lets say 2 Units), without changing the shape. So basically using vertices like Pixels.

currently, as seen in the following picture, the faces are very irregular in size and thus the vertices are in very different distances to each other: 
[image]

My approach was to subdivide the surfaces for like 10 times, until the biggest distance between vertices is below my minimum distance (2 units). I then need a method to remove vertices in such a way, that there are no vertices closer to each other than the minimum distance.

The result would hopefully be that the vertices are all about in the same distance to each other ()

Also any other approach to achieve this would be great!

Thanks

Comment: Use *Remove doubles* and increase the threshold to collapse vertices too close to each other. You can also use the *Dyntopo* sculpting to do similar thing with a brush just on parts you want to change. You will loose volume of the mesh in both cases.

Comment: It could be a job much more related to something like http://www.meshlab.net/

Comment: Thanks everyone! That was helpful! "Remove doubles" is one very well working approach

Answer (score 0):

Using "remove Double" after subdivinding multiple times did the job, thanks @Jaroslav Jerryno Novotny!